# How can I activate GeoTIFF compression in QGIS 3.x gdal_translate?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing

I am a beginner at Python so please excuse this stupid question. I am working on a simple QGIS plug-in for saving GeoTIFFs and I want to give the user the option to switch on compression when saving them. So I wrote:

```
...
algresult = qgis.processing.run("gdal:translate", {
                        'creationOptions': ["COMPRESS=JPEG", "JPEG_QUALITY=60"],
                        'INPUT': str(layer.name()),
                        'outputSRS': dst_crs,
                        'OUTPUT': layer_filename_r})
...
```

The image is written correctly but uncompressed, the creationOptions are ignored. Instead of 'creationOptions' I also used 'OPTIONS', but I couldn't find a working example for this. gdal_translate definitely supports compression options, because it's in the qgis dialog. I'm running QGIS 3.24.2.

Comment: This worked! It was the pipe symbol. Thank you very much for your help, @BERA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `'OPTIONS':'COMPRESS=JPEG|JPEG_QUALITY=60'`

I executed the tool manually in QGIS, pressed Ctrl+Alt+H to see the command syntax:

[image]

Comment: Ha! So that's how you get the correct syntax! I always tried to extrapolate from the command prompt syntax you get in the algorithm dialog box.